# Trouble getting Debian to recognize monitor resolution

Tags: debian, xrandr, display-settings

I had an MSI Nvidia GT 710 video card connected to an [Asus MG24UG](https://www.cnet.com/products/asus-mg24uq-led-monitor-23-6/) display (3840 x 2160, 60 Hz) via HDMI, and was able to configure Debian to output graphics at the full resolution. Then I swapped out that card for an MSI Nvidia GTX 1050 Ti card (max res: 7680x4320@60Hz) because it has a DisplayPort connector (which latches, making things a little more secure). But I have been unable to get the OS to support the native resolution, and I can't figure out why.

Here’s what I tried:

```
~ $ cvt 3840 2160
# 3840x2160 59.98 Hz (CVT 8.29M9) hsync: 134.18 kHz; pclk: 712.75 MHz
Modeline "3840x2160_60.00"  712.75  3840 4160 4576 5312  2160 2163 2168 2237 -hsync +vsync
~ $ xrandr --newmode "3840x2160_60.00"  712.75  3840 4160 4576 5312  2160 2163 2168 2237 -hsync +vsync
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
~ $ xrandr --addmode default "3840x2160_60.00"
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
~ $ xrandr --output default --mode "3840x2160_60.00"
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
xrandr: screen cannot be larger than 1024x768 (desired size 3840x2160)

~ $ xrandr --listactivemonitors
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Monitors: 1
 0: +*default 1024/271x768/203+0+0  default
~ $ xrandr --screen 0
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1024 x 768, current 1024 x 768, maximum 3840 x 2160
default connected primary 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      76.00* 
   3840x2160_60.00  59.98
```

The larger size shows up in the System Settings displays GUI, too, but attempting to choose it results in the same error.

I also don’t understand why it can’t auto-detect the display capabilities without me having to manually set up these modes.

Comment: Take a look at https://askubuntu.com/a/441075/141639

Comment: I'm not sure what part of that answer you're asking me to look at. The only display I have is "default", and I added the mode to that.